# How to render complex glyphs using Magick++

Tags: arabic, hindi, magick++

I have some code rendering labels on a picture using `Magick++` (`Image::annotate` method).
Almost all scripts are displayed correctly but I'm getting troubles with Devanagari and Arabic. These languages have [several](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari#Letters) glyphs per symbol depending on symbol position in the word. In the resulting image each symbol is rendered as if it is the only symbol in the word, something like (for Arabic):

م رح ب ا

instead of

مرحبا

Is it possible to render the labels correctly?

Comment: Finally I've implemented rendering using freetype2 & icu4c, imagemagick is now used for images compositing only.